# Where is the ServiceManager object initialized in the Zend Framework 2 User Guide?

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-framework-modules, servicemanager

In the album example of the Zend Framework 2 User Guide the model is configured like this:

```
<?php
namespace Album;

// Add these import statements:
use Album\Model\Album;
use Album\Model\AlbumTable;
use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;

class Module
{
    // getAutoloaderConfig() and getConfig() methods here

    // Add this method:
    public function getServiceConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'Album\Model\AlbumTable' =>  function($sm) {
                    $tableGateway = $sm->get('AlbumTableGateway');
                    $table = new AlbumTable($tableGateway);
                    return $table;
                },
                'AlbumTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                    $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                    $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                    $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Album());
                    return new TableGateway('album', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
                },
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

The variable `$sm` is a `Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager` object. But how/when/where is it created/initialized?

EDIT:

What I want to know, is: How/where does `$sm`  get its value (and become a ServiceManager object).

Comment: I'd wait for a Answer from one of the ZF2-Devs, but my ASSUMPTION would be this line: https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php#L737

Comment: If you're using the skeleton app, it's instantiated by `Application::init()` here -> https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Mvc/Application.php#L236

Comment: Thank you for your replies guys! I'm still not getting, how it can work. I've just tried to formulate my question exacter, s. EDIT.

Comment: @automatix, when you retrieve a service from a service manager, if it's a factory, it passes an instance of itself as the first parameter to whichever `callable` is responsible for creating the service, that will usually be either a `closure` (as in your example), or the `createService` method of a factory class. This is done, in the case of factories, by the code here -> https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php#L859

Comment: @Crisp I agree with you, post this as an answer so it can help others with similar question

Comment: @StoyanDimov, wasn't sure if it classed as an answer, however, since you agree, I've added it :)

Comment: So basically i was right? Yay, i understand the framework a little bit after all :D

Answer (score 1):

When you retrieve a service from a service manager, if it's a factory, it passes an instance of itself as the first parameter to whichever callable is responsible for creating the service, that will usually be either a closure (as in your example), or the createService method of a factory class.

This is done, in the case of factories, by the code here https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php#L859

Basically, in your module you're telling the ServiceManager that those services are created by calling the closures you provided. When you ask the ServiceManager to `get()` one of them the first time, it'll determine it's a factory (it was supplied in the factories key in config), then figure out if it's a closure or an instance of FactoryInterface (a factory class), and finally call it appropriately to instantiate your service.

Comment: Thank you for your comments and the answer! I think, I'm stuck... I've tried to debug the Application and especially the `ServiceManager#createFromFactory()`, but cannot find the point, where `$sm` gets its value. ZF2 is hard to debug and hence hard to learn/unterstand (for me anyway). If it's not too much effort, could you (or somebody else) please describe step by step the whole chain to the place in the code, where `$sm` is initialized and gets the value. Something like a commented stack trace. It would be really great. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: The line that @Sam linked in your OP is where the $sm gets its value, the line `$instance = call_user_func($callable, $this, $cName, $rName);` where the second param `$this` is the `ServiceManager` instance passed to `call_user_func`, that becomes  the `$sm` instance you receive as first param of your closure